# splitting underscores in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365

I'm fairly new to Excel and need some assistance. I have a Column that has a list of files that look like:

```txt
12345_v1.0_TEST_Name [12345]_01.01.2022.html
45321_v55.9_Some Name Here [64398]_07.15.2018.html
56871_v14.2_Test[64398]_10.30.2019.html
```

Each file name can be different depending on what output is provided to me.

Note: There are other random files in the same format, however where it says Test_Name there could be an underscore and sometimes no underscore. Would like that to be ignored in the formula or vba. Files also can change but will be in the same format.

I need some help with a formula or vba that splits the underscores and outputs the data into their own cells:

```txt
Column C    12345
Column D    v1.0
Column E    TEST_Name [12345]
Column F    01.01.2022
Column G    .html
```

Comment: The `Split` function has the option to specify a delimiter like the underscore... is that what you need? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: You can run a `Replace(myString, "TEST_Name", "TEST Name")` to avoid the unwanted split in the middle of that value.

Comment: @braX Thank you for the reply, but unfortunately that's not what I was looking for as I have to specify a string. The list of my files changes, but in the same format

Comment: Version of Excel?

Comment: @Skin Excel 365 version 16

Comment: Will the name ALWAYS be "TEST_Name" ?

Comment: It looks like the issue is just the 1st two underscores, the closing bracket, and the last period. Could probably be handled with `MID()`, `SEARCH()`, and `LEN()` functions.

Comment: @user3683976 so i have tried using an `Old Skool Approach`, you may need to adjust the few relevant like `TEST_Name` as per your data, I have assumed as per the infor provided by you in the query.

Comment: @braX TEST_Name and the rest of the string will be different as well. So for example it could be 12345_v1.0_TEST_Name [12345]_01.01.2022.html or 45321_v55.9_Some Name Here [64398]_07.15.2018.html, etc.....

Comment: @user3683976 it will be better if in your query you had shared some samples at `5` to `6`, so it will be more clearer, to provide solutions, we don't know what is your data be like, only `1 string` is not enough for solving a query,

Comment: @Mayukh Bhattacharya I went ahead and updated my post with some more example of output. Output will be different depending what is giving to me. Each time output is provided it will be different....

Comment: @user3683976 I apologize for the same, however, it can be assumed that the pattern will not always be same, but you could have updated the query in the beginning itself, anyways. `Power Query` or `VBA` will be right approach or may be `FILTERXML`!

Comment: @user3683976 it is very hard to assume now, a name can be a string of 4 words or may be 6 words, also there can be 4 underscores or more than that, occurrences can differ as well, !

Comment: @user3683976 please refer in answers i have updated with as per given information and some assumption.

Answer (score 1):

> *There are other random files in the same format.....Files also can change but will be in the same format.*

So, assuming the files indeed will be in the same format, we can brake this query down into the following requirements:

- Change the 1st and 2nd occurence and the very last of the underscore into anything to split on;
- Change the dot before the file-extension into anything to split on under the assumption we don't know if this would be '.html' or any other extension.

Since you have Microsoft365 we can use dynamic arrays and some basic functions to retrieve what you want:

[image]

```
=LET(X,SEARCH("_??.??.????.",A1),Y,"</s><s>",TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1,X,12,Y&MID(A1,X+1,10)&Y),"_",Y,2),"_",Y,1)&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

---

To break this down a little bit:

- `SEARCH("_??.??.????.",A1)` - This part will make sure that we find the position of the very last underscore upto the dot before the file extension **assuming** you don't have any other date in your filenames in this specific format;
- `SUBSTITUTE()` - We can use this formula to specifically change the 1st and 2nd instances of the underscore to anything we can split on;
- `FILTERXML()` - You may notice we used valid xml start/end-tags to split our data using this function.
- `TRANSPOSE()` - This last function will now spill the returned array over the columns instead of rows.

---

Without `LET()`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1,SEARCH("_??.??.????.",A1),12,"</s><s>"&MID(A1,SEARCH("_??.??.????.",A1)+1,10)&"</s><s>"),"_","</s><s>",2),"_","</s><s>",1)&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

Comment: When I tried the formula I get an Invalid Name Error

Comment: It looks like I can't use LET for some reason. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @user3683976, see the edited answer for an non-LET alternative.

Answer (score 1):

*Since there can be different file extensions however the format remains same, hence the above formula which i provided has been amended with some few tweaks so that it works for any file extensions,*

**FORMULA IN CELL C1**

```
=IF(LEN($B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B1,"_",""))+1>4,

TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($B1,"."&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE($B1,"."," ",LEN($B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B1,".","")))," ",REPT(" ",200)),100)),"_"&"."&
TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($B1,"."," ",LEN($B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B1,".","")))," ",
REPT(" ",200)),100))),"_"," ",3),"_",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN(A1)*99-98,100)),

TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($B1,"."&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
$B1,"."," ",LEN($B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B1,".","")))," ",REPT(" ",200)),100)),"_"&"."&
TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($B1,"."," ",LEN($B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B1,".","")))," ",
REPT(" ",200)),100))),"_",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN(A1)*99-98,100)))
```

**FILL DOWN & FILL ACROSS!!!**

[image: FORMULA WORKS ANY FILE EXTENSIONS]

Comment: Love the formula. I did notice on row Column A the example is 12345_v1.0_Test_Name [12345]_01.02.2022.html but then when I plug the formula in above it separates everything correctly except for: Test Name [12345]. Not sure why its removing the underscore in TEST_Name

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve, although there might be more eloquent way to use a formula, and solve this, however you may try using this as well,

**FORMULA USED IN CELL C1**

```
=IF(LEN($B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B2,"_",""))+1>4,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($B2,".html","_.html"),"_"," ",3),"_",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN(A2)*99-98,100)),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($B2,".html","_.html"),"_",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN(A2)*99-98,100)))
```

**Fill Down & Fill Across !**

[image: SPLITTING_UNDERSCORES]

Comment: Is there a way to account for different file extensions. Formula works on my end great. Just want to account for different file extensions

Comment: @user3683976 then you might need to `SUBSTITUTE` the `FILENAME` with `File Extension`, since in the above formula, `.html` is hard coded it shall not work. Let me fix it!

Comment: thank you. Let me know when its fixed and I'll retests it again :)

Comment: @user3683976 i have added an answer, please check ! However with `LET` Function it can be made short since `LET` isn't working in your version, hence that big formula!